# Unity 3, generic type not resolving, type does not have an accessible constructor

Tags: unity-container, ioc-container

I have the following registration.  The goal is that when IDbSet needs to be injected it will be extracted out of the requests IDataContext.

```
container.RegisterType<IDbSet<AuditRound>>(new InjectionFactory(c => c.Resolve<IDataContext>().AuditRounds));
var thisReturnsTrue = container.Registrations.Any(e => e.RegisteredType == typeof(IDbSet<AuditRound>));
var fails = container.Resolve<IDbSet<AuditRound>>();
```

it fails with the message that The type DbSet`1 does not have an accessible constructor.  It seems like it's trying to use the convention ISomeClass resolves to SomeClass, in this case IDbSet to DbSet.  I do see a registration for IDbSet in the registrations and it seems to be taking precedence.  Any help is appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Make sure you have a **public** constructor available for the type you're trying to create.

Comment: I'm not constructing it, the registration is a call back function which should be returning the instance.

Comment: The thing that constructs it still needs an accessible constructor.

Comment: thanks OMGtechy but that isn't the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My issue turned out to be that the convention registration "RegisterTypes" was registering IDbSet to DbSet.  This registration was taking precedence over my own other registration.  I tried changing the order but that did not help.  I had to exclude DbSet from my registration routine.  Exclusions are a parameter on container.RegisterTypes.